# File Permissions - Service vs Console

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, service, file-permissions, jenkins

We have just setup a new build Windows 2008 R2 server for our Jenkins CI system. Our issue appears to be related to file permissions being different depending on whether a process is a service, or a console process.

When logged in as UserX, we can successfully do a directory listing of `dir /b c:\Windows\System32\q*.exe` (actual command), and it returns 6 files. However, running the same command through a service, we only get 5. Same user account. Same computer.

The bigger issue is that, because the file doesn't appear in a directory listing, it can't be executed.

There doesn't appear to be any differences in the permissions between the files that do appear, and the one that doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We figured this problem out, so I'm posting the solution for others.

The problem was that the Jenkins slave process (the service) was running as a 32-bit process. Windows, being helpful, was automatically redirecting access to c:\Windows\System32 to c:\Windows\SysWOW64.

The executables we were looking for should have been in SysWOW64 anyway, so we copied them across, and the problem has been solved.